# HTML Динамическое изменение размеров объектов

Tags: html

Надо что-бы при нажатии на область объекта можно было произвольно менять размер и остальные объекты произвольно меняли свой.
Может кто наблюдал на "просторах" готовый вариант.

[image: Описание]

Comment: Т.е. нажать и растягивать блок?

Comment: Да, ты правильно понял